# Search in a column from a vector of strings using R

Tags: r

I have column with address.I want to parse it and just have the state name.Below is my column

```
structure(list(BreweryName = c("(512) Brewing Company", "0 Mile Brewing Company", 
"10 Barrel Brewing", "10 Barrel Brewing - Eastside Pub", "10 Barrel Brewing - Portland Pub", 
"10 Barrel Brewing Co."), BreweryAddress = c("407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
"11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
"1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States", "62950 NE 18th StBend, Oregon, 97701United States(541) 241-7733", 
"1411 NW Flanders StPortland, Oregon, 97209-2620United States(541) 585-1007", 
"830 W Bannock StBoise, Idaho, 83702-5857United States(208) 344-5870"
)), row.names = c(4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have another vector from there I want to compare it and replace .

```
v<- c("Texas","Pennsylvania","Oregon","Oregon","Idaho")
```

I did try using `match` and `grep` but it returned with `NA's`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: a column with the state name if it matches

Comment: @RonakShah You also need word boundaries in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. We can basically concatenate the states into a single pattern with `|` as the separator, to indicate any of them can be options, and then extract from the address column. This is pretty rough (what if a brewery is at Idaho Ave?) but depending on your data this is probably enough.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(BreweryName = c("(512) Brewing Company", "0 Mile Brewing Company", "10 Barrel Brewing", "10 Barrel Brewing - Eastside Pub", "10 Barrel Brewing - Portland Pub", "10 Barrel Brewing Co."), BreweryAddress = c("407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States", "62950 NE 18th StBend, Oregon, 97701United States(541) 241-7733", "1411 NW Flanders StPortland, Oregon, 97209-2620United States(541) 585-1007", "830 W Bannock StBoise, Idaho, 83702-5857United States(208) 344-5870")), row.names = c(4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L), class = "data.frame")
v <- c("Texas","Pennsylvania","Oregon","Oregon","Idaho")
df %>%
  mutate(State = str_extract(BreweryAddress, str_c(v, collapse = "|")))
#>                        BreweryName
#> 1            (512) Brewing Company
#> 2           0 Mile Brewing Company
#> 3                10 Barrel Brewing
#> 4 10 Barrel Brewing - Eastside Pub
#> 5 10 Barrel Brewing - Portland Pub
#> 6            10 Barrel Brewing Co.
#>                                                                BreweryAddress
#> 1    407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545
#> 2 11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133
#> 3                          1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States
#> 4              62950 NE 18th StBend, Oregon, 97701United States(541) 241-7733
#> 5  1411 NW Flanders StPortland, Oregon, 97209-2620United States(541) 585-1007
#> 6         830 W Bannock StBoise, Idaho, 83702-5857United States(208) 344-5870
#>          State
#> 1        Texas
#> 2 Pennsylvania
#> 3         <NA>
#> 4       Oregon
#> 5       Oregon
#> 6        Idaho
```

Created on 2018-09-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `grepl`:

```
v <- c("Texas","Pennsylvania","Oregon","Oregon","Idaho")
states <- paste0("\\b", v, "\\b", collapse="|")
states

[1] "\\bTexas\\b|\\bPennsylvania\\b|\\bOregon\\b|\\bOregon\\b|\\bIdaho\\b"

df[grepl(states, df$BreweryAddress), ]
```

I printed out `states` so that it is clear what regex pattern we are using to search the brewery addresses.  We are using an *alternation* of each state name, enclosed in word boundary markers.  This ensures that we don't accidentally match a string which happened to contain some state name as a substring.

Answer (score 0):

library stringr has easy approach for this

```
v<- c("Texas","Pennsylvania","Oregon","Oregon","Oregon","Idaho")

library(stringr)
demographics$State <- str_extract(demographics$BreweryAddress,fixed(v, ignore_case=TRUE)) ##i have saved your data as demographics data frame.
```

Answer (score 0):

A  baseR solution using `regmatches, gregexpr`

data:

```
df1 <-
structure(list(BreweryName = c("(512) Brewing Company", "0 Mile Brewing Company", 
                               "10 Barrel Brewing", "10 Barrel Brewing - Eastside Pub", "10 Barrel Brewing - Portland Pub", 
                               "10 Barrel Brewing Co."), BreweryAddress = c("407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545", 
                                                                            "11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133", 
                                                                            "1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States", "62950 NE 18th StBend, Oregon, 97701United States(541) 241-7733", 
                                                                            "1411 NW Flanders StPortland, Oregon, 97209-2620United States(541) 585-1007", 
                                                                            "830 W Bannock StBoise, Idaho, 83702-5857United States(208) 344-5870"
                               )), row.names = c(4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L), class = "data.frame")

v     <- c("Texas","Pennsylvania","Oregon","Oregon","Idaho")
```

code:

```
v_mod <- paste0(v, collapse="|")

df1$states <- sapply(regmatches(df1$BreweryAddress, gregexpr(v_mod, df1$BreweryAddress)), function(x){if(length(x)==0) NA else x})
```

result:

```
#                        BreweryName                                                              BreweryAddress       states
#4             (512) Brewing Company    407 Radam LnSte F200Austin, Texas, 78745-1197United States(512) 921-1545        Texas
#6            0 Mile Brewing Company 11 W 2nd StHummelstown, Pennsylvania, 17036-1506United States(717) 319-0133 Pennsylvania
#8                 10 Barrel Brewing                          1501 E StSan Diego, California, 92101United States         <NA>
#10 10 Barrel Brewing - Eastside Pub              62950 NE 18th StBend, Oregon, 97701United States(541) 241-7733       Oregon
#12 10 Barrel Brewing - Portland Pub  1411 NW Flanders StPortland, Oregon, 97209-2620United States(541) 585-1007       Oregon
#14            10 Barrel Brewing Co.         830 W Bannock StBoise, Idaho, 83702-5857United States(208) 344-5870        Idaho
```